# Ruby On Rails Method Clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I was given this ruby code to overview. I am still new to ruby on rails. I come from a java background.

in User.rb:

```
  def last_name=name
    require 'debugger'; debugger
    self[:last_name] = name
  end
```

And told me that this is a setter method. They told me that this get executed in the "form" in this line:

```
<%= f.label :last_name%>
<%= f.text_field :last_name %>
```

Ok. Could somebody clarify how this ridiculous syntax can be valid?

1) An instance of the class "User" is never initialized. How is the method even called?

2) Where does the variable "name" comes from? what is the value of it? (the variable name is called nowhere else) And what does this syntax stand for?  "def last_name=name" ?? Pass to the method a variable that has not been initialized? It is a short-cut for another syntax just to save typing 2 more symbols?

3) How can this method be called, in the form? I dont see a "User.last_name("David") or anything similar.

Could somebody clarify those piece of code please?
And please dont post links to tutorial or anything else. Just clarify this piece of code

Comment: Homework? Despite your request, I have to suggest you to read an introduction to Rails and Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you described:

```
<%= f.label :last_name%>
<%= f.text_field :last_name %>
```

..is used by the default rails template engine. It is view code.

**1) A User instance is likely initialized and populated when the form is submitted.**

The form action corresponds to an appropriate controller action, which likely accepts `:last_name` as a parameter. When you submit the form, the controller action probably instantiates the User instance. Without more code, however, I can't be 100% certain this is the case with your application.

**2) The variable `name` comes from the argument accepted by the `last_name` method.**

Perhaps, to help you understand the method, let's rewrite it:

```
def last_name= (name)
  require 'debugger'; debugger
  self[:last_name] = name
end
```

Either `last_name=('John Doe')` or `last_name = 'John Doe'` will execute this method.

**3) I think my previous descriptions should help you make sense of this..**

Comment: thanks, now it makes sense. so what 'def last_name(name)...' do then? It should do the same right? but it doesnt when I try

Comment: It's probably most simple to consider ruby function calls in a manner which consists of a name and also possibly an operator. Think of the `=` sign as an operator, and, `def last_name (name)`, which defines a method that is executed as `last_name('John Doe')` as a method with no operator definition. Ruby then maps the `=` operation for that symbol (the name) to the method. You should read this short article: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/

Answer (score 0):

1. MVC.  In the action new a new instance of User is created and assigned to @user, which is what will be used for the form.
2. name comes from the method declaration `def last_name=name`
3. The form helpers does last_name=name when it assigns a value to that variable and uses the setter to do that.  When you edit the object it will use the getter to display its value in the text field.

Comment: "form helpers does last_name=name when it assigns a value to that variable" so when the user assign a value to the form, name (which is null) goes into the last_name variable?

Comment: Yes.  As long as @user is not null.  And you can uses attr_accessor that will create that for you automatically. http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html

Answer (score 0):

You can understand better point #2 with this syntax:

```
def last_name=( name )
end
```

The `=` is part of the function's name.

C equivalent would be

```
void last_name_equals( char *name ) {}
```

The rest is a Rails tutorial's job.

Comment: I still don't get it. So what you are telling me, is that, "take variable name, which is null, and puts its null value in last_name?

Comment: @TestTest: No, `name` is just the name of the variable. If you call instance.last_name = `"foo"`, `name` will contain `"foo"` in your method.